Problem web-scraping table with BeautifulSoup
I have just started with Python and am looking to scrape web data from the https://afltables.com/.
When I select the first Australian Rules team (Adelaide) the page provides me with 20 tables of match to match records against the other 20 teams
https://afltables.com/afl/teams/adelaide/allgames_tm.html
I can see that the first table of results (matches against Brisbane) has an [id] of sortableTable0 but when I try referencing this (or any of the other tables) my code doesn't pick the Table up.
Table shown in Chrome Developer mode
A loop through the tables on the page detects there are sortable tables but I also wasn't able to use this method to return a table to work with.
Is this an issue with my code or is it website related?
What I want to be able to do is eventually parse our all the matches for each club row by row
TIA
My code
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test1', 'test2'])
URL = "https://afltables.com/afl/teams/adelaide/allgames_tm.html"
print(URL)
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())
table = soup.find('table',id='sortableTable2')
#table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'sortable') 
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    test1 = columns[0].text.strip()  
    test2 = columns[1].text.strip()
    df = df.append({'test1': test1,  'test2': test2}, ignore_index=True)
    df.head 


beautifulsoup doesn't care about what you see in chrome. have you checked what is getting out of requests?

I had looked but didnt see the the table information in the requests

As I understand your question, you want to select all "sortable" tables content and convert them to dataframe. Here is the code with key as each club name:
from io import StringIO 
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://afltables.com/afl/teams/adelaide/allgames_tm.html"
print(URL)
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# ALL SORTABLE TABLES
tables = soup.select(".sortable")

# WILL BE HOLDING CONTENT for against each club by key
tables_record_dict =  {}


for table in tables:
    # creating df by providing table content and choosing Rnd, T line as header
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)), header=0)[0].drop(0)
    club_name = table.select_one("thead").select_one("th").text
    print(club_name)
     
    tables_record_dict[club_name] = df


print(tables_record_dict)

Output:
A Dataframe Output In Jupyter




Rnd
T
Opponent
Scoring
F
Scoring.1
A
R
M
W-D-L
Venue
Crowd
Date




1
R14
H
Brisbane Bears
3.2 9.3 12.9 15.12
102
1.2 5.6 10.7 14.10
94
W
8
7-0-2
Football Park
34183
Sat 06-Jul-1996 8:10 PM


2
R17
H
Brisbane Bears
0.4 3.4 5.8 6.10
46
1.2 7.2 10.5 11.10
76
L
-30
6-0-2
Football Park
33829
Sun 30-Jul-1995 5:15 PM


3
R2
A
Brisbane Bears
4.0 7.7 11.9 14.15
99
7.4 10.8 15.14 18.18
126
L
-27
6-0-1
Gabba
9334
Sun 09-Apr-1995 1:15 PM


4
R21
H
Brisbane Bears
7.2 8.5 10.8 13.11
89
2.4 7.9 8.9 12.14
86
W
3
6-0-0
Football Park
36599
Sun 14-Aug-1994 3:45 PM


5
R6
A
Brisbane Bears
1.3 4.8 10.10 18.13
121
3.2 8.5 13.6 17.8
110
W
11
5-0-0
Gabba
9457
Sat 30-Apr-1994 2:08 PM


6
R10
A
Brisbane Bears
2.4 7.10 10.14 18.14
122
5.4 8.5 11.9 12.13
85
W
37
4-0-0
Gabba
12395
Sun 30-May-1993 2:15 PM


7
R21
A
Brisbane Bears
5.1 9.1 14.7 17.8
110
5.2 8.6 10.8 11.11
77
W
33
3-0-0
Carrara
4603
Sun 09-Aug-1992 2:10 PM


8
R6
H
Brisbane Bears
4.4 12.10 17.15 19.20
134
3.1 5.3 8.5 11.8
74
W
60
2-0-0
Football Park
42759
Sun 26-Apr-1992 1:40 PM


9
R14
H
Brisbane Bears
3.7 5.10 14.11 23.18
156
2.1 5.7 10.9 13.12
90
W
66
1-0-0
Football Park
35355
Sun 23-Jun-1991 1:40 PM


10
Totals
Totals
Totals
143.121
979
119.104
818
P:9 W:7 D:0 L:2
P:9 W:7 D:0 L:2
P:9 W:7 D:0 L:2
NaN
218514
NaN


11
Averages
Averages
Averages
16.13
109
13.12
91
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
24279
NaN




As noted, your first look should be at the response / soup, as this is the basis for your selections with BeautifulSoup.
However, since you are already using pandas why do not you just use pandas.read_html() to scrape the tables? This is the simplest approach from my point of view and always worth an initial try.
Example
import pandas as pd

df_list = []

# read tables into list of dataframes and iterate over
for df in pd.read_html('https://afltables.com/afl/teams/adelaide/allgames_tm.html'):
    # drop the team header from column multiindex
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
    # append dataframe slicing last two rows (totals, ...) to df_list
    df_list.append(df.iloc[:-2,:])

pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)






Rnd
T
Opponent
Scoring
F
Scoring
A
R
M
W-D-L
Venue
Crowd
Date




0
R14
H
Brisbane Bears
3.2 9.3 12.9 15.12
102
1.2 5.6 10.7 14.10
94
W
8
7-0-2
Football Park
34183
Sat 06-Jul-1996 8:10 PM


1
R17
H
Brisbane Bears
0.4 3.4 5.8 6.10
46
1.2 7.2 10.5 11.10
76
L
-30
6-0-2
Football Park
33829
Sun 30-Jul-1995 5:15 PM


...















767
R21
A
Footscray
0.1 2.4 4.4 6.4
40
3.6 3.9 4.13 8.16
64
L
-24
1-0-1
Western Oval
11452
Sat 10-Aug-1991 2:10 PM


768
R6
H
Footscray
3.1 8.7 13.9 19.14
128
4.4 7.6 11.10 14.13
97
W
31
1-0-0
Football Park
36695
Sun 28-Apr-1991 5:10 PM




Thanks for the help. I tried this code (using Thonny) but couldnt generate the sample output. Did I miss a step?

Not familiar with thonny, therefore assume that you have to make the result visible with a print statement, if this is not done automatically, as for example in jupyter notebooks.

You could build the data for your dataframe as a list of lists and then just create the DataFrame once.
Something like this:

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from functools import cache

URL = "https://afltables.com/afl/teams/adelaide/allgames_tm.html"

@cache
def parser():
    try:
        import lxml
        parser = "lxml"
    except Exception:
        parser = "html.parser"
    return parser

def get_columns(html):
    soup = BS(html, parser())
    tr = soup.select_one("table.sortable thead tr")
    return [th.text for th in tr.select("th")]


def get_content(html):
    content = []
    soup = BS(html, parser())
    for tr in soup.select("table.sortable tbody tr"):
        content.append([td.text for td in tr.select("td")])
    return content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with requests.get(URL) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        html = response.text
        columns = get_columns(html)
        content = get_content(html)
        df = pd.DataFrame(content, columns=columns)
        # then, for example, extract rows based on Opponent name
        print(df.loc[df["Opponent"] == "Footscray"].to_string(index=False))

Output:
Rnd T  Opponent              Scoring   F              Scoring   A R   M W-D-L         Venue  Crowd                     Date
 R9 A Footscray  2.3 4.7 6.10 11.13   79  5.3 9.5 12.9 18.11  119 L -40 3-0-6  Western Oval  11140  Sat 25-May-1996 2:10 PM
R11 H Footscray 4.6 6.10 8.15 12.18   90    1.1 2.7 3.8 6.10   46 W  44 3-0-5 Football Park  36955  Sat 10-Jun-1995 8:10 PM
R20 A Footscray    1.3 2.5 4.8 4.10   34 3.1 8.7 13.10 17.16  118 L -84 2-0-5  Western Oval  17591  Sun 07-Aug-1994 2:08 PM
 R5 H Footscray   4.5 4.5 8.8 13.15   93  2.2 11.4 15.7 17.8  110 L -17 2-0-4 Football Park  44426 Sun 24-Apr-1994 12:45 PM
R11 H Footscray 1.3 8.8 10.14 15.17  107   2.7 2.9 5.13 8.14   62 W  45 2-0-3 Football Park  44979  Sun 13-Jun-1993 3:38 PM
R16 A Footscray     2.2 4.6 6.6 8.8   56 6.3 10.4 16.8 22.11  143 L -87 1-0-3 Waverley Park  13235  Sat 04-Jul-1992 2:10 PM
 R1 H Footscray  2.3 6.9 6.11 12.15   87 6.3 9.5 13.11 17.12  114 L -27 1-0-2 Football Park  40381  Sun 22-Mar-1992 1:40 PM
R21 A Footscray     0.1 2.4 4.4 6.4   40   3.6 3.9 4.13 8.16   64 L -24 1-0-1  Western Oval  11452  Sat 10-Aug-1991 2:10 PM
 R6 H Footscray  3.1 8.7 13.9 19.14  128 4.4 7.6 11.10 14.13   97 W  31 1-0-0 Football Park  36695  Sun 28-Apr-1991 5:10 PM

